# Is id in all table a good schema design for MongoDB?

Tags: database-design, mongodb, schema

We are designin User and Order collection.

In our User collection, we already has `DBRef` referencing to Order collection but our manager asked us adding an extra field in the order collection.

```
  Existing collections
  Users:
  {
    "_id": "user001",
    "orders": [DBref('order', 'order001'),DBref('order', 'order002')],
    ...
  }

  Orders:
  {
    "_id": "order001",
    "amount": 123,
    "user": DBref('users', 'user001'), <--- new requirment from manager
    ...
  }
```

My concern is the id maybe not match for some human mistake(i.e someone updated the users field in the order collection but forgot to update the array). Will it be a "single source of truth" problem or another foreseeable problem? Manager would like to view the owner of the Order clearly in Mongo Compass. For my understand, we can use $lookup for checking the order's owner.

Answer (score 0):

> My concern is the id maybe not match for some human mistake(i.e someone updated the users field in the order collection but forgot to update the array). Will it be a "single source of truth" problem...

Sure, that's certainly a potential problem with the design choice your manager wants you to make. It's good you're thinking ahead on those kinds of things.

This is where normalized tables, typically in a RDBMS (SQL database), with proper constraints, prevents you from such data integrity issues. And a view could be used to unify the the `Users` and `Orders` tables so anyone could "*view the owner of the Order clearly*" without compromising on that data integrity.